# SVG elements lose event listeners after transform

Tags: javascript, svg, transform

When the parent `<svg>` transform attribute is programmatically changed, I got some weird behaviours of inner SVG elements. Neither css selectors (like `:hover`) nor javascript listeners (`onClick`) are working after the change.

Here is an example:

- A simple `<svg>` containing a `<circle>` element:

  ```
  <svg width="200" height="200">
      <circle cx="30" cy="30" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" r="20" onClick="alert('clicked')">
      </circle>
  </svg>
  ```
- JS code that updates `<svg>` transform attribute after each window click:

  ```
  var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0]
  var x = 0
  window.onclick = function() {
    svg.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + x + ',' + x + ')')
    x += 3
  }
  ```

https://jsfiddle.net/ohpaaevt/6/

Could anybody shed some light on this ?

**EDIT** : I just noticed that applying transform attribute on `<svg>` doesn't even work on Chrome, only on Firefox. Haven't tested with other browsers.

Comment: There are syntax errors in the fiddle you need ' rather than ` in a couple of places in setAttribute

Comment: Could you include your code in the post? Link off site is not considered good posting practice. - Also, I think you meant "lose" not "loose".

Comment: @RobertLongson I used ES6 string templates. Here is a version without them https://jsfiddle.net/ohpaaevt/6/

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thank you for the notice. I added some code & explanations.

Comment: Thank you. It's much appreciated. Also, I can't see what units you are giving your transform...

Comment: @evolutionxbox According to this article, no unit is needed https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform

Comment: Try transforming the circle and not the svg element itself. To transform the svg element itself I think you do need to provide units as it's a css transform not an svg transform.

Comment: Oh, good catch ! But the problem with this approach is that I have a graph with lots of svg elements and I want to perform translating on all of them at the same time. So transforming one by one might cause performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforms on `<svg>` elements are a new feature of SVG 2 that only Firefox has implemented. In SVG 1.1 the `<svg>` element does not support having a transform attribute.

SVG 2 is a new specification and is as yet unfinished. Chrome, Firefox and IE Edge have implemented different parts of it.

To work around the lack of suport in Chrome create a `<g>` child of the `<svg>` and move all the contents of the `<svg>` into the `<g>` element and then transform the `<g>` element rather than the `<svg>` element.